# Preemption and sleeping during a spinlock atomic context

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

We know that to lock a spinlock disables preemption on the relevant processor. So now, suppose that the kernel code executed calls a function which sleeps the process. Despite the preemption deactivation, Will the Linux kernel give the processor to another thread?

Answer (score 3):

It depends. There are series of `cond_resched()` functions that are checking if preempt bits are set and thus disabling reschedule:

```
/*
* Returns true when we need to resched and can (barring IRQ state).
*/
static __always_inline bool should_resched(void)
{
    return unlikely(!preempt_count() && tif_need_resched());
}

int __sched _cond_resched(void)
{
    if (should_resched()) {
        __cond_resched();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But not all kernel routines do that. I.e. mutexes directly call `schedule_preempt_disabled()`, which ignores atomicity checks. In that case, `schedule()` will try to give CPU to another task, but will complain about "scheduling while atomic".